# Sed / Awk - Find string exactly n characters long

Tags: sed, grep, awk

Looking through the man pages for sed, awk and grep, I'm unable to find a way to search for a string that is exactly n characters long.

Given the following text file, I want to extract just `6982a9948422`

```
ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND                
CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
6982a9948422        ubuntu:12.04        apt-get install ping   
1 minute ago        Exit 0
```

The value will always be in the first column and is always 12 alphanumeric characters.

Here is what I am trying so far.

```
 cat /tmp/test | awk {'print $1'} | sed 's/.*\([0-9],[A-Z],[a-z]\{12\}\).*//g'
```

What would be a way to extract just `6982a9948422` from the text above ?

Comment: In your case, you can use `docker ps -q` and avoid having to do text manipulation at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
awk 'length($1) == 12 { print $1 }' file
```

The program is pretty self documenting and avoids the regex hammer.

```
awk -v f=1 '$f ~ /^[[:alnum:]]{12}$/ { print $f }' file
```

Or swing away with the above if you only want to consider first fields (fields being delimited by blanks) that consist only of alphanumeric characters.

With `awk` implementations that don't support the `{x,y}` interval regular expressions, you can change it to:

```
awk -v f=1 'length($f) == 12 && $f !~ /[^[:alnum:]]/ { print $f }' file
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will pick up non-alphanumerics, too.

Comment: @JosephR., that has been addressed.

Answer (score 6):

This will search for, and print, all alphanumeric strings that start at the beginning of a line and are exactly 12 characters long.

```
grep -o -w -E '^[[:alnum:]]{12}'
```

For macOS users. Install GNU grep for this to work. 
Can be done using [homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193300).

Comment: This works on (GNU grep) 2.10 [ubuntu] but not on (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD [MacOsX]

Comment: I tried to make it POSIX compliant. It works on FreeBSD 9.1. I don't have access to a Mac OS X system, sorry.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer, I just wanted to clarify for any future readers who might be confused why it doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` with the PCRE facility. It's available in most of the newer versions of `grep`.

```
$ grep -oP "^[[:alnum:]]{12}" test.txt
6982a9948422
```

This will give you all the matches that are 12 long and include characters that are valid in words, `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: This works on (GNU grep) 2.10 [ubuntu] but not on (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD [MacOsX]

Comment: @spuder - please update your Q then, you need to be explicit if you have locked versions of OS/tools, otherwise with the generic tags you've selected the A'ers are left to guess.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer, I just wanted to clarify for any future readers who might be confused why it doesn't work for them.

Comment: @spuder - OK, next time just make note that this is just a heads up or something, otherwise that comment might be perceived as this A doesn't solve the OP's problem. Mainly b/c it's you the OP making mention of this. 8-). Is your Q resolved then or did you want additional feedback?

Answer (score 1):

**AWK Solution**

```
awk '{match( $1, /[0-9A-Za-z]{12}/, arr) }; { printf arr[0] }' inputFile
```

OR

```
awk '$1 ~ /[0-9A-Za-z]{12}/{print $1}' inputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using end-of-word delimiter, not apparent in any of the solutions above:

```
egrep '^[[:alnum:]]{12}\>' filename
```

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html Because it isn't standardized, thus may not work everywhere. which seems to be a untold part of the question from reading his comments.

Comment: Also, careful with what `\>` (or `\b` or `[[:>:]]`) means where available. That's usually the transition from a word character (the definition of which varies) to a non-word character. For instance, the above will generally match on `123456789012-456` because that `\>` matches inbetween the `2` and `-` as `2` is a _word character_ and `-` is not.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your own solution. Instead of deleting any `$1` that doesn't match the required regexp, use `grep` to filter them out:

```
awk '{print $1}' /tmp/test | grep -iE '^[a-z0-9]{12}$'
```

Alternatively in pure `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{12\}\)[ \t]\+.*/\1/' /tmp/test
```

Comment: That `sed` code does not work.  This does: `sed -n 's/^\([[:alnum:]]\{12\}\)[[:space:]].*/\1/p' /tmp/test`.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given you answers for your specific test case where the string in question is at the beginning of the line. These solutions will print *all* strings that consist of 12 consecutive word characters:

```
perl -lne 'print for /\b(\w{12})\b/g;' file
grep -oP '\b(\w{12})\b' file
```

Answer (score 0):

No `grep`, `awk`, etc., just pure POSIX shell:

```
while read x y ; do case "$x" in ????????????) echo $x ;; esac ; done < test
```

Output:

```
6982a9948422
```

If the match needs to be *strictly* alphanumeric, there's always *this*:

```
while read x y ; do case "$x" in \
    [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]) echo $x ;; \
                    esac ; \
done < test
```

Answer (score -2):

This will process any line that has 12 alphanumeric characters and print the first field:

```
awk '/[[:alnum:]]{12}/ {print $1}' file
```